# removing relevant hyphens in text

Tags: python, python-2.7

Lets say I have text which looks like:

a = "I am inclin- ed to ask simple questions"

I would like to first extract the hyphenated words, i.e first identify if hyphen is present in the text, this is easy. I use re.match("\s*-\s*", a) for instance to check if the sentence has hyphens.

1) Next I would like to extract the preceding and following partial words (I this case I would like to extract "inclin" and "ed")

2) Next I would like to merge them into "inclined" and print all such words.

I am stuck at step 1. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> a = "I am inclin- ed to ask simple questions"
>>> result = re.findall('([a-zA-Z]+-)\s+(\w+)', a)
>>> result
[('inclin-', 'ed')]

>>> [first.rstrip('-') + second for first, second in result]
['inclined']
```

Or, you can make the first group save the word without the trailing `-`:

```
>>> result = re.findall('([a-zA-Z]+)-\s+(\w+)', a)
>>> result
[('inclin', 'ed')]
>>> [''.join(item) for item in result]
['inclined']
```

This will also work for multiple matches in the string:

```
>>> a = "I am inclin- ed to ask simp- le quest- ions"
>>> result = re.findall('([a-zA-Z]+)-\s+(\w+)', a)
>>> [''.join(item) for item in result]
['inclined', 'simple', 'questions']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ou thtis regex, it should work well for you:

```
a = "I am inclin- ed to ask simple questions"

try:
    m = re.search('\S*\-(.|\s)\S*', a) #this will get the whole word, i.e "inclin- ed"
except AttributeError:
    #not found in a

print m
```

then you strip your string, and grab them as an array.

Comment: I think re.findall('([a-zA-Z]+)\s*-\s*(\w+)', a) captures the problem better

Comment: Thing about Regex you can write many ways of doing one thing, so whatever works for you, i just thought that maybe you would have an apostrophe or special character in there.

But I hope that helped.